# Objective-c regular expression for " (null) "

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Anyone know how to write a regular expression for `"  null     "` where the whitespace could be any length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\\s*` to match zero or more space characters.

```
"\\s*null\\s*"
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive match then add case-insensitive modifier `(?i)` at the start, so that it would match `Null` or `null`, etc.

```
"(?i)\\s*null\\s*"
```